# How can I get these collisions to work properly?

Tags: javascript, collision-detection

I managed to get the collisions somwhat working in my javascript game, but only the top left corner of the player collides. I have already tried a dozen different ways to fix this but none of them worked.

Heres my code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var source = new Image(548, 64);
source.src = "dungeon.jpg";
var FX = 0;
var FY = 0;
var BX = 0;
var BY = 0;
let dir = "";

let rightPressed = false;
let leftPressed = false;
let upPressed = false;
let downPressed = false;

var map = {
  cols: 9,
  rows: 8,
  tsize: 64,
  tiles: [
    3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1,
    1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3,
  ],
  getTile: function(col, row) {
    return this.tiles[row * map.cols + col];
  },
};

var player = {
  x: 200,
  y: 200,
  dx: 0,
  dy: 0,
  size: 32,
};

console.log("drawing tilemap");
console.clear();
ctx.font = "30px Arial";
ctx.fillText("nvm its not working", 10, 50);
draw_map();
draw_player();

function draw_map() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
  ctx.fillRect(FX, FY, 10, 10);

  for (var column = 0; column < map.cols; column++) {
    for (var row = 0; row < map.rows; row++) {
      const tile = map.getTile(column, row);
      const x = column * map.tsize;
      const y = row * map.tsize;
      drawTile(tile, x, y);
    }
  }
}

function drawTile(tile, X, Y) {
  if (tile === 1) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#34ed4d";
  }
  if (tile === 2) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#fff291";
  }
  if (tile === 3) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#9c9ea1";
  }
}

function draw_player() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "#fff200";
  ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, 32, 32);
}

function keyDownHandler(e) {
  if (e.key === "Right" || e.key === "ArrowRight") {
    rightPressed = true;
  } else if (e.key === "Left" || e.key === "ArrowLeft") {
    leftPressed = true;
  }
  if (e.key === "Up" || e.key === "ArrowUp") {
    upPressed = true;
  } else if (e.key === "Down" || e.key === "ArrowDown") {
    downPressed = true;
  }
}

function keyUpHandler(e) {
  if (e.key === "Right" || e.key === "ArrowRight") {
    rightPressed = false;
  } else if (e.key === "Left" || e.key === "ArrowLeft") {
    leftPressed = false;
  }
  if (e.key === "Up" || e.key === "ArrowUp") {
    upPressed = false;
  } else if (e.key === "Down" || e.key === "ArrowDown") {
    downPressed = false;
  }
}

function loop() {
  player.dx = 0;
  player.dy = 0;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 512, 512);
  if (rightPressed) {
    FX = player.x + 2;
  } else if (leftPressed) {
    FX = player.x - 2;
  }
  if (upPressed) {
    FY = player.y - 2;
  } else if (downPressed) {
    FY = player.y + 2;
  }

  collisions();
  draw_map();
  draw_player();
}

function collisions() {
  for (var column = 0; column < map.cols; column++) {
    for (var row = 0; row < map.rows; row++) {
      const tile = map.getTile(column, row);
      const X = column * map.tsize;
      const Y = row * map.tsize;
      if (FX + 1 > X && FX < X + 64 && FY + 1 > Y && FY < Y + 64) {
        // ohhh my god collision
        if (tile === 3 || tile === 4 || tile === 5 || tile === 6) {
          console.log("no sir you cant go there");
        } else {
          player.x = FX;
          player.y = FY;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);

setInterval(loop, 10);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="576" height="512" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
  Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas>
```

I tried to get the player to collide on all four sides but only the corners work no matter what I try.

Answer (score 0):

A basic collision detection approach for two rectangles looks like this.  I'm assuming variables `x`, `y`, `w`, `h` for position and size starting from top-left corner.

```
function detectCollision(obj1, obj2) {
    return ((obj1.x+obj1.w > obj2.x) && (obj1.x < obj2.x+obj2.w) 
         && (obj1.y+obj1.h > obj2.y) && (obj1.y < obj2.y+obj2.h));
}
```

You could either conform your objects' naming convention to match, or build your own temporary objects to pass into that function.

```
let obj1 = { x:FX, y:FY, w:player.size, h:player.size };
let obj2 = { x:X, y:Y, w:map.tsize, h:map.tsize };
```

Comment: i know how to get rectangle collision detection to work but i dont know how to stop a rectangle from entering the collision area.

Comment: Your use of `FX+1` suggests you were close, but didn't quite know how collision detection works.  Your use of testing an (x,y) coordinate before conditionally assigning it suggests you do know how to prevent a moving object from entering a collision area.